# FCFS implemention for xv6

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, xv6

Currently for my college project, I am trying to implement FCFS and Priority scheduling algorithms for xv6. I am done with the priority one and now trying to make FCFS work out. The following is the modification i did to the code:

```
void
scheduler(void)
{
  struct proc *p = 0;

  struct cpu *c = mycpu();
  c->proc = 0;

  for(;;)
  {
      // Enable interrupts on this processor.
      sti();

      // Loop over process table looking for process to run.
      acquire(&ptable.lock);
      for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++)
      {

            struct proc *minP = 0;

            if(p->state != RUNNABLE)
              continue;

            // ignore init and sh processes from FCFS
            if(p->pid > 1)
            {
              if (minP != 0){
                // here I find the process with the lowest creation time (the first one that was created)
                if(p->ctime < minP->ctime)
                  minP = p;
              }
              else
                  minP = p;
            }

            // If I found the process which I created first and it is runnable I run it
            //(in the real FCFS I should not check if it is runnable, but for testing purposes I have to make this control, otherwise every time I launch
            // a process which does I/0 operation (every simple command) everything will be blocked
            if(minP != 0 && p->state == RUNNABLE)
                p = minP;

          if(p != 0)
          {

            // Switch to chosen process.  It is the process's job
            // to release ptable.lock and then reacquire it
            // before jumping back to us.
            c->proc = p;
            switchuvm(p);
            p->state = RUNNING;

            swtch(&(c->scheduler), p->context);
            switchkvm();

            // Process is done running for now.
            // It should have changed its p->state before coming back.
            c->proc = 0;
          }
        }

        release(&ptable.lock);
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to ask is that when I run two dummy process (doing with the convention, foo.c to produce children processes to do useless calculations that consume time) each producing a child, why is it that I am still able to run ps?

Technically, each of the 2 available CPUs must be occupied running the two dummy process correct?

Additionally, I set the creation time as Priority using the algoirthm i wrote for the Priority scheduling. Turns out, after creation of the two processes, I cannot run anything, meaning both the CPUs are in use right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made two mistakes:

1. the process context is *inside* your `for` loop, it should be after:

   ```
   schedule()
   {
       // for ever
       for(;;) 
       {
            // select process to run
            for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++)
            {                 
               ...
            }

            // run proc
            if (p != 0)
            {                 
               ...
            }
       }
   ```
2. You've made a little mistake in `minP` selection:

   ```
   if(minP != 0 && p->state == RUNNABLE)  
       p = minP;
   ```

   should be

   ```
   if(minP != 0 && minP->state == RUNNABLE)
      p = minP;
   ```

   but since `minP`'s `state` is necessary `RUNNABLE`, and that you test that it's not null before running it, you could write

   ```
      p = minP;
   ```

---

So you're corrected code could be:

```
void
scheduler(void)
{
    struct proc *p = 0;
    struct cpu *c = mycpu();
    c->proc = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        sti();

        struct proc *minP = 0;

        // Loop over process table looking for process to run.
        acquire(&ptable.lock);
        for(p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++)
        {
            if(p->state != RUNNABLE)
                continue;

                // ignore init and sh processes from FCFS
                if(p->pid > 1)
                {
                    if (minP != 0) {
                        // here I find the process with the lowest creation time (the first one that was created)
                        if(p->ctime < minP->ctime)
                            minP = p;
                    }
                    else
                        minP = p;
                }

        }
        p = minP;
        release(&ptable.lock);

        if(p != 0)
        {

            c->proc = p;
            switchuvm(p);
            p->state = RUNNING;

            swtch(&(c->scheduler), p->context);
            switchkvm();

            c->proc = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a first for me! I am getting an indentation error in C! Anyway to fix it? Just a minor update change, I think the minP must be declared outside the for loop to prevent any declaration error!

Comment: @ShabbirKhandwala indeed, `minP` must be declared before the `for`loop. About the *indentation* (?) it,s strange, what is the error message ?